# How to return value from a jsp page

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have a jsp page which has java scriplets, and which is displaying the required output using `out.println(obj)`, but I want to return this `'obj'` so that these values can be used in another js file. How to return this from the jsp page?

So the js file is:

```
(function() {

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

        var gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: [
                {headerName: 'CLIENT_ACRONYM', field: 'CLIENT_ACRONYM'},
                {headerName: 'ORDER_QTY', field: 'ORDER_QTY'},

            ]
        };

        new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

        jsonLoad( function(data) {
            gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
        });
    });
    })();


function jsonLoad(callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', '../output.json'); // by default async
    xhr.responseType = 'json'; // in which format you expect the response to be

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status == 200) {// onload called even on 404 etc so check the status
            callback(this.response);
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log('loading data error');
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

JSP file returning Jsonarray:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(orderDetailsList1);

response.setContentType("application/json");
       response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       response.getWriter().write(jsonArray);
```

So, instead of output.json in the js file I need to pass the JSOn Object returned by the jsp file. How to do that?

Comment: use this to hold your value ,`var myVar="<%out.println(obj);%>";` now use the `myVar` inside javascript.

Comment: jsp should not have java code in them.  Use servlets for java code.  Use session attributes to store small objects temporarily.

Comment: What are you trying to pass the value to?  Back to the server: use a form, To a different jsp file on the same page, just set the variable, and include the other jsp.

Comment: @Kelvin So the test.jsp needs to return json object, which I need to use in sample.js

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh  And how to use it in my sample.js file?

Comment: declare global value to store the value and use it everywhere.

Comment: I am return json value, so if I do it by declaring global variable, it gives me null value in the js file.

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699202/passing-a-variable-from-scriptlets-to-javascript)

Comment: Just to let you know. I want to use it in an external javascript file in the same folder. Have a look at my question here for better understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377079/how-to-pass-json-object-from-jsp-to-external-js-file/39379030?noredirect=1#comment66087632_39379030

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code in jsp file**

`<input type="hidden" value="<%out.println(obj);%>" id="objValue"/>`

**In js file you can get the value by its `id` as**

`var objValue = document.getElementById("objValue");`

Basically scriplets in `jsp` is not good.

Store in session scope or request scope and use it,like `session.setAttribute('obj','value')` in servlet and `value="${obj}"` in jsp.

Comment: Do I need to import/call my test.jsp file in the sample.js file in order to do that?

Comment: Or in index.html? If yes, then how to do that?

Comment: Include the **sample.js** file in your **test.jsp** file using **script tag**, here is an example to do that:           `<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/sample.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm doing what you're saying, but I'm getting null value for jsonArray in the js file.

Comment: in **jsp** `<input type="hidden" value="<%response.getWriter().write(jsonArray);%>" id="objValue"/>` and in **js** use `var objValue = document.getElementById("objValue");`

Answer (score 0):

Put that value in `<div id="">` or `<p id="">` tag which has ID in jsp and get that value in any js using getElementByID.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated code in the question and tell me how that can be done.